Relation between finite abelian monoids and finite abelian groups
I'm reading the first part of the book "Representation Theory of Finite Monoids" by Steinberg on finite monoids and in the section 1.1 he wrote "a finite monoid is a collection of finite groups loosely tied together by a partially ordered set". But he didn't explained what he means exactly by that. Does someone has more details about this or maybe a reference which explains that ?
Moreover, I'm interested in finite abelian monoid and I was wondering, does exist for abelian monoid a result like "every finite finite abelian monoid is a direct sum of finite cyclic monoid" (like for finite abelian groups) ?
Thank you
